# How to update multiple table row array in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, multiple-tables

it display the record but when I save it. it doesnt work. please have a check on my array query.

```
<form action="saveupdaterecord.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">   
    <table>
                  <tr>
                     <?php
            $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM famcomp WHERE app_id='".     mysql_real_escape_string($app_id) ."'");
            $result->execute();
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
          ?>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="app_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['app_id']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fullname[]" value="<?php echo $row['fullname']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fage[]" value="<?php echo $row['fage']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="frel[]" value="<?php echo $row['frel']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fcivil[]" value="<?php echo $row['fcivil']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fedu[]" value="<?php echo $row['fedu']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="foccup[]" value="<?php echo $row['foccup']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="finco[]" value="<?php echo $row['finco']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
                </tr>    
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
    <br></table></form>
```

saveupdaterecord.php

```
$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$N = count($fullname);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
mysql_query("UPDATE 'famcomp' SET 'fullname' = '".$_POST["fullname[$i]"]."', fage = '".$_POST["fage[$i]"]."', frel = '".$_POST["frel[$i]"]."', fcivil = '".$_POST["fcivil[$i]"]."', fedu = '".$_POST["fedu[$i]"]."', foccup = '".$_POST["foccup[$i]"]."', finco = '".$_POST["finco[$i]"]."' WHERE `app_id` = '".$_POST["app_id"]."'"); // Run the Mysql update query inside for loop
$message = 'Success Updating the record!!';
echo "<SCRIPT>alert('$message');</SCRIPT>";
echo "<script>windows: location='editrecord.php?name=$a'</script>";
```

Comment: You are not passing the index to $_POST["app_id"].

Comment: is there any other option to update multiple row?. I use for loop to loop the total COUNT($fullname)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `'famcomp'` use `famcomp`

Also as raveenanigam said you havent used `$_POST["app_id[$i]"]`. If still gets the problem, try using

```
     mysql_query("UPDATE famcomp SET 
     fullname = '".$_POST["fullname[$i]"]."', fage = '".$_POST["fage[$i]"]."',
     frel = '".$_POST["frel[$i]"]."', fcivil = '".$_POST["fcivil[$i]"]."', 
fedu = '".$_POST["fedu[$i]"]."', foccup = '".$_POST["foccup[$i]"]."',
     finco = '".$_POST["finco[$i]"]."'
     WHERE `app_id` = '".$_POST["app_id[$i]"]."'") 
or die(mysql_error()); // Run the Mysql update query inside for loop
```

**Edit** : Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['fullname']))
{
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    echo "Got the Fullname";
    foreach( $fullname as $key => $n ) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE famcomp SET 'fullname' = '".$_POST[fullname[$key]]."', fage = '".$_POST["fage[$key]"]."', frel = '".$_POST["frel[$key]"]."', fcivil = '".$_POST["fcivil[$key]"]."', fedu = '".$_POST["fedu[$key]"]."', foccup = '".$_POST["foccup[$key]"]."', finco = '".$_POST["finco[$key]"]."' WHERE app_id= '".$_POST["app_id[$key]"]."'") or die(mysql_error());

        $message = 'Success Updating the record for ' . $n;
    }
}
else
    echo "Cannot get Fullname";
```

Comment: I'm getting this: Notice: Undefined index: fullname in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSWD System\admin\saveupdaterecord.php on line 22

Comment: @kim de castro, also change `'fullname'`  to `fullname`

Comment: I got an error here: $N = count($fullname); Notice: Undefined variable: fullname

Comment: your new code doesnt have an error. but it doesnt change any. can you check my form? I use for loop.

Comment: I forgot APP_ID is a foreign key.

Comment: @kimdecastro, Again edited the code. Now run this & check if it prints `Cannot get Fullname`

Comment: it says "Cannot get Fullname"

Comment: it says Cannot get Fullname

Comment: It means the problem is with the `fullname` value. You are not even getting the `$_POST['fullname']` data. So, it is not saving anything in the database. Check for how you are sending the data!!

Comment: I use the form above. it display the record by APP_ID connecting pk to fk. but i dont know why it doesnt get the full name when Updating.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes to table name and Use foreach for looping the data.

`foreach($fullname as $key){ mysql_query("UPDATE famcomp SET 'fullname' = '".$_POST[fullname[$key]]."', fage = '".$_POST["fage[$key]"]."', frel = '".$_POST["frel[$key]"]."', fcivil = '".$_POST["fcivil[$key]"]."', fedu = '".$_POST["fedu[$key]"]."', foccup = '".$_POST["foccup[$key]"]."', finco = '".$_POST["finco[$key]"]."' WHERE`app_id`= '".$_POST["app_id"]."'"); }`

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="<?php echo $row['app_id']; ?>" /> is this right?

Comment: If appId is constant then it is fine. Iam not sure whether it will allow underscore aren't. _ (or) - in these one is not allowed in names.

Comment: I forgot APP_ID is a foreign key.

Comment: Foreign key / primary key is irrelevant to php, to  store the data in to a variable. if it isn't contant go for an array .. i mean name="appID[]"

Comment: my form display the result. but when I edit it still getting error using your foreach =(

Comment: initially check whether you are getting post data from previous page . And let me know the error info i.e occuring at foreach..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$N = count($fullname);
for($i = 0 ;$i< count($fullname); $i++) {
$query = "UPDATE famcomp SET app_id = '".$_POST["app_id[$i]"]."', fullname = '".$_POST["fullname[$i]"]."', fage = '".$_POST["fage[$i]"]."', frel = '".$_POST["frel[$i]"]."', fcivil = '".$_POST["fcivil[$i]"]."', fedu = '".$_POST["fedu[$i]"]."', foccup = '".$_POST["foccup[$i]"]."', finco = '".$_POST["finco[$i]"]."' WHERE app_id = '".$_POST["app_id[$i]"]."'"; // Run the Mysql update query inside for loop
mysql_query($query, $con);
$message = 'Success Updating the record!!';
echo "<SCRIPT>alert('$message');</SCRIPT>";
echo "<script>windows: location='editrecord.php?name=$a'</script>";
}
```

Add this to your php

```
<?php
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM famcomp WHERE app_id='".     mysql_real_escape_string($app_id) ."'");
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","password","database"); //you can check this in priviledges. name of your database, if user has no password do not include password, delete "password", 
if (!$con){
die("Can't connect".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("database",$con); //the name of your database
?>
```

Comment: $fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$N = count($fullname); I'm having problem with this.  undefined variable. i dont know why it doesnt get the fullname post.